# What spell gives immunity to damage for all creatures in an area?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, content-identification

In a previous game, I encountered a high level spell courtesy of my DM that rendered everyone within that radius, allies and enemies, invulnerable to all damage. I was wondering if anyone recognized the effect?

Answer (score 11):

#### The closest spell is *globe of invulnerability*.

There is no spell that gives immunity to all damage for creatures in an area. The spell *invulnerability* is 9th level (the highest possible spell level), and can only be cast on yourself:

> You are immune to all damage until the spell ends.

The next closest effect is probably *globe of invulnerability*, which has a 10-foot radius and protects against spells:

> An immobile, faintly shimmering barrier springs into existence in a 10-foot radius around you and remains for the duration.
>
> Any spell of 5th level or lower cast from outside the barrier can't affect creatures or objects within it, even if the spell is cast using a higher level spell slot. Such a spell can target creatures and objects within the barrier, but the spell has no effect on them. Similarly, the area within the barrier is excluded from the areas affected by such spells.

That said, if the effect was exactly as you describe, complete immunity for all creatures in the area, it’s likely a homebrewed effect.

Comment: Note that in Baldur's Gate 3, the *globe of invulnerability* does in fact make everyone inside immune to all damage, so there could be some confusion generated from that.